# Tree structure from array paths using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, tree, treeview

I am getting a json structure given below form an api which contains paths of related children in an array form .
for example here is my json structure

```
[
  {
    "name": "Children C1",
    "path": [
      "A",
      "B",
      "C"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Children C2",
    "path": [
      "A",
      "B",
      "C"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Children C3",
    "path": [
      "A",
      "B",
      "C"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Children B1",
    "path": [
      "A",
      "B"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Children B2",
    "path": [
      "A",
      "B"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Children A1",
    "path": [
      "A"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Children E1",
    "path": [
      "D",
      "E"
    ]
  }
]
```

Here path is the route for a childeren. For example first object means 
-A
  -B
  -C
   - Childeren C1

and so on . I am using tree view library which requires only this structure

```
var tree=[
  {
    'Name': 'A',
    'children': [
      {
        Name: '',
        children: [

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and so on. I want to convert my path structure to tree. Need help I can I achieve this with plain javasript.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result=input.reduce((obj,el)=>{
 var orig=obj;
  for(key of el.path){
    var found=obj.find(e=>e.name===key);
    if(found){
      obj=found.children;
    }else{
      var temp={name:key, children:[]};
      obj.push(temp);
      obj=temp.children;
    }
 }
 obj.push(el.name);
return orig;
},[]);
```

http://jsbin.com/cowowisaji/edit?console

It creates the following structure:

```
[{
  name:"A",
  children:[
    "Children A1",
   {name:B", children:[...]}
  ]
}]
```

It simply iterates over all elements and resolves the path trough searching the right path object in an array, if a path element does not exist it creates it.

The upper code can be shortified to:

```
var result=input.reduce((obj,el)=>(el.path.reduce((path,name)=>(path.find(e=>e.name==name)||(path[path.length]={name:name,children:[]})).children,obj).push(el.name),obj),[]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another approach with a helper object for keeping the reference to the named objects.

```js
var data = [{ name: "Children C1", path: ["A", "B", "C"] }, { name: "Children C2", path: ["A", "B", "C"] }, { name: "Children C3", path: ["A", "B", "C"] }, { name: "Children B1", path: ["A", "B"] }, { name: "Children B2", path: ["A", "B"] }, { name: "Children A1", path: ["A"] }, { name: "Children E1", path: ["D", "E"] }],
    tree = function (array) {
        var result = [],
            o = { _: result };

        array.forEach(function (a) {
            a.path.concat(a.name).reduce(function (r, b) {
                if (!r[b]) {
                    r[b] = { _: [] };
                    r._.push({ name: b, children: r[b]._ });
                }
                return r[b];
            }, o);
        });
        return result;
    }(data);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```